How can I pass the value of a multiselect picklist with a List Button?
Many related questions discuss passing multi-select picklist values in other situations. None of them were applicable to a simple list button to create a new record and passing default values from the origination record, to include a multi-picklist value.
Here's an example of a desired List Button formula, where FieldTwo__c is a multi-picklist:
{!URLFOR( '/lightning/o/Custom_Object__c/new?recordTypeId=111222333444IAG
  &defaultFieldValues=FieldOne__c=' + Other_Object__c.FieldOne__c 
  + ',FieldTwo__c=' + OtherObject__c.FieldTwo__c)}

This results in an error on save, though:

Error: Field FieldTwo__c is a multi-select picklist field. Multi-select picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

Documentation: Tips for Working with Picklist and Multi-Select Picklist Formula Fields
How can I accomplish this?

Here's how my team worked around this unfortunate deficiency in Salesforce's functionality.

Create a new field to store the text value of the multi-select picklist (FieldTwo_Text__c).

In the beforeInsert and beforeUpdate contexts of a trigger handler for the custom object, assign the stringified value of the picklist to the new field:


  for (CustomObject__c newObj : (List<CustomObject__c>)Trigger.new) {
    newObj.FieldTwo_Text__c = String.valueOf(newObj.FieldTwo__c);
  }


Pass the text field value in the List Button's formula:

{!URLFOR( '/lightning/o/Custom_Object__c/new?recordTypeId=111222333444IAG
  &defaultFieldValues=FieldOne__c=' + Other_Object__c.FieldOne__c 
  + ',FieldTwo__c=' + OtherObject__c.FieldTwo_Text__c)}

The standard new record page will parse the string value and populate the multi-select picklist with the appropriate selections.
